# How to yield a child process created by fork(), then other child processes have chance to run?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, fork, pipe

In my program, I create 3 child processes and then assign them to do a same thing which is decreasing a number. the program stops when the number=0. I use 2 pipes to communicate between parent and child process.

```
int  a;
int main(void)
{

a=10;
//declare and create 2 pipes
int p1[2], p2[2];
pipe(p1);
pipe(p2);
    int ra;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{   
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) 
    {
        close(p1[1]);
        close(p2[0]);
        read(p1[0],&ra,3);

        while(ra>0)
        {

            ra-=1;
            printf("%i a are available, reported by process %i\n",ra,getpid());
            close(p1[0]);
            write(p2[1],&ra,3);

            close(p2[1]);

        }
        break;

    }
    else
    if(pid>0)
    {


    }else
    {
        wait(NULL);

    }

}
  }
 if(pid>0)
{
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        if(a>0)
        {
            write(p1[1],&a,3);
            close(p1[1]);
        }
        else
            exit(0);
        read(p2[0],&ra,3);
        a=ra;
        close(p2[0]);


}
```

My problem is there only one child process running and decreasing a value until a=0. other processes dont have a chance.
How can I fix that? thank in advance

Comment: Start by posting something besides empty control blocks. We don't know what you're doing wrong without seeing the code, so avoid the lengthy "are you doing 'blah' ?" exchange and post what you have so far please. If each child process is to "hand off" the next decrement to the next child, you need some pretty well-defined arrangement of your pipes. I'd start with that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just edited it. Please, have a look

Comment: Usually, the purpose of this kind of exercise is to decrement `a`, write the value into the pipe, then read it back from the pipe.  That way, each child is contending to read a value and each will typically run.

Comment: parents process write the a value to pipe1, child processes read it and decrease 1, then write it back to the pipe via pipe2. parents read value from pipe2 and check if value > 0 or not. If yes, then parents write value back to child processes. The program stops when a=0;

Comment: Right. So each child is supposed to read the value from the pipe on each iteration.  There's no point in having the parent write the value of the children aren't reading it. Blocking for the read will allow other children to run.

Comment: @WilliamPursell sorry, But I dont get your idea. do you mean, the read in parent process is blocking other children, so I need to remove it? if yes, it doesnt solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have each child block on a read from the parent on each iteration of the loop.  For example, the child code should be something like:

```
while( read( p1[0], &a, sizeof a ) == sizeof a ) {
  a -= 1;
  write( p2[1], &a, sizeof a );
}
```

and the parent code should look like:

```
do {
    write( p1[1], &a, sizeof a );
} while( read( p2[0], &a, sizeof a ) == sizeof a && a > 0 );
close( p1[1] );
```

This makes each child block on a read after decrementing the counter, thus going to sleep until the parent is scheduled.  After the parent writes a value into the appropriate pipe, only one of the children that is blocking on a read will be awakened to decrement the counter.

Comment: +1 This is near-exactly what I see this exercise trying to teach.

Comment: I dont know why it is not working. it printed out only one line "35 a are available, reported by process 2546".

Comment: Why do you have a `wait()` call inside the first loop?  The parent is waiting for the first child to finish, and the child is waiting for the parent to write something into the pipe.